# mongodb add field from another collection

Tags: mongodb

I try to add field from another collection.

```
db.CarModifications.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: "CarTypes",
        localField: "CarTypeID",
        foreignField: "CarTypeID",
        as: "carType"
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
      CarType  : "$carType._id"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$CarType"
},
{
    $project: {
        someField: 0
    }
}
]).forEach(function(result) {
    db.CarModifications.updateOne({_id: result._id}, {$set: {"CarType": result.CarType}})
})
```

Aggregation result show correct, but no documents update. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you show your sample dataset and the complete aggregation pipeline? It seems that some part in the last `$project` stage is omitted and might be relevant to the symptoms.

Comment: Can you verify what are the values in the `result` variable?